# JS - Using toLocaleString() to get the right format

Tags: javascript, date

I saved my date in Mongoose Schema as `default: new Date()`

Here's what I get when printing `post.date`: `2020-07-29T13:03:23.584Z`

I want to remove the `T13:03:23.584Z` part, I used `post.date.toLocaleString()` and it didn't change it, still have `2020-07-29T13:03:23.584Z`

Comment: You can pass the TZ into the toLocaleString function.  
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' }));

Comment: can you share a code? don't know what TZ means

Answer (score 0):

Syntax :

Date.toLocaleString(locales, options)

and an example for my locale :

```
 var d = new Date(); 
 var n = d.toLocaleString("tr-TR",{dateStyle :"short"});
```

and it prints : 29.07.2020

You can set dateStyle option with "full" or "long" or "medium" or "short"

[Additional information here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp)

Comment: This works on jsfiddle, but not on my app... I guess it has to do with how Mongoose stores date.. where this T13:03:23.584Z is coming from?